# GWT - How to allow only numbers in TextItem?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have the following `TextItem`:

```
final TextItem txtFromAmt = new TextItem();
txtFromAmt.setWrapTitle(false);
txtFromAmt.setShowTitle(false);
txtFromAmt.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
txtFromAmt.setWidth(100);
```

I want this `TextItem` to only allow numbers. How can I do that? Is there any property/method of `TextItem` to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below documentation.

https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#setKeyPressFilter-java.lang.String-

As suggested by El Hoss try the same

```
txtFromAmt.setKeyPressFilter("[0-9.]"); // allows only digits and .(dot)
```

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything different to what El Hoss answered. His answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: And for validation purposes its better to use `FloatItem` widget instead of `TextItem`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
    txtFromAmt.setKeyPressFilter("[0-9]");
```

Hope that helps.